# Python string replace in a file without touching the file if no substitution was made

Tags: python, file-io, replace

What does Python's string.replace return if no string substitution was made?
Does Python's file.open(f, 'w') always touch the file even if no changes were made?

Using Python, I'm trying to replace occurrences of 'oldtext' with 'newtext' in a set of files.  If a file contains 'oldtext', I want to do the replacement and save the file.  Otherwise, do nothing, so the file maintains its old timestamp.

The following code works fine, except all files get written, even if no string substitution was made, and all files have a new timestamp.

```
for match in all_files('*.html', '.'):  # all_files returns all html files in current directory     
  thefile = open(match)
  content = thefile.read()              # read entire file into memory
  thefile.close()
  thefile = open(match, 'w')             
  thefile.write(content.replace(oldtext, newtext))  # write the file with the text substitution
  thefile.close()
```

In this code I'm trying to do the file.write only if a string substitution occurred, but still, all the files get a new timestamp:

```
count = 0
for match in all_files('*.html', '.'):       # all_files returns all html files in current directory
    thefile = open(match)
    content = thefile.read()                 # read entire file into memory
    thefile.close()
    thefile = open(match, 'w')
    replacedText = content.replace(oldtext, newtext) 
    if replacedText != '':
        count += 1
        thefile.write(replacedText)
    thefile.close()
print (count)        # print the number of files that we modified
```

At the end, count is the total number of files, not the number of files modified.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

I'm using Python 3.1.2 on Windows.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to replace all the strings **'oldtext'** present in a file with strings **'newtext'** ? Or that you want to replace the occurences of the string hold by the object of name  ``oldtext``  with the string hold by the object of name ``newtext`` ? In the first case there is a good way to do it with very little work.

Comment: @eyquem - 1st case.  I want to replace all strings 'oldtext' with 'newtext' and I only want to rewrite the file if a substitution occurred.  So if there is no occurrence of 'oldtext' in the file, then the file should not get updated.  The solutions by @unutbu and @J.F. Sebastian both work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What does Python's string.replace
>   return if no string substitution was
>   made?

It returns the original string.

> Does Python's file.open(f, 'w') always
>   touch the file even if no changes were
>   made?

More than merely touching the file, it destroys any content `f` used to contain.

So, you can test if the file needs to be rewritten with `if replacedText != content`, and only open the file in write mode if this is the case:

```
count = 0
for match in all_files('*.html', '.'):       # all_files returns all html files in current directory
    with open(match) as thefile:
        content = thefile.read()                 # read entire file into memory
        replacedText = content.replace(oldtext, newtext)
    if replacedText!=content:
        with open(match, 'w') as thefile:
            count += 1
            thefile.write(replacedText)
print (count)        # print the number of files that we modified
```

Comment: This works, thanks.  And thanks to J.F. Sebastian for explaining why it works.

Answer (score 4):

> What does Python's string.replace return if no string substitution was made?

[`str.replace()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?#str.replace) returns the string itself or a copy if the object is a subclass of string.

> Does Python's file.open(f, 'w') always touch the file even if no changes were made?

[`open(f, 'w')`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) opens and truncates the file `f`.

Note the code below is CPython specific; it won't work correctly on pypy, jython:

```
count = 0
for match in all_files('*.html', '.'):
    content = open(match).read()
    replacedText = content.replace(oldtext, newtext) 
    if replacedText is not content:
       count += 1
       open(match, 'w').write(replacedText)
print (count)
```

Comment: You mean `if replacedText is not content`, don't you?

Answer (score 3):

Your case is a particular case: **'newtext'** has exactly the same number of characters as **'oldtext'**.

Hence, it is possible to use one of the following codes to replace exactly a word **'oldtext'** or a line in which the word **'oldtext'** is present, by word **'newtext'** or a line in which **'newtext'** replaces **'oldtext'**.

.

If files have not super-big size, the content of each file can be read entirely into memory:

```
from os import fsync      # code using find()

count = 0
for match in all_files('*.html', '.'):
    with open(match,'rb+') as thefile:
        diag = False
        fno = thefile.fileno()
        content = thefile.read()
        thefile.seek(0,0)
        x = content.find('oldtext')
        while x>=0:
            diag = True
            thefile.seek(x,1)
            thefile.write('newtext')
            thefile.flush()
            fsync(fno)
            x = content[thefile.tell():].find('oldtext')
    if diag:
        cnt += 1
```

or

```
from os import fsync     # code using a regex
import re
pat = re.compile('oldtext')

count = 0
for match in all_files('*.html', '.'):
    with open(match,'rb+') as thefile:
        diag = False
        fno = thefile.fileno()
        content = thefile.read()
        thefile.seek(0,0)
        prec = 0
        for mat in pat.finditer(content):
            diag = True
            thefile.seek(mat.start()-prec,1)
            thefile.write('newtext')
            thefile.flush()
            fsync(fno)
            prec = mat.end()
    if diag:
        cnt += 1
```

.

For heavy files, a reading and rewriting line after line is possible:

```
from os import fsync   # code for big files, using regex
import re
pat = re.compile('oldtext')

count = 0
for match in all_files('*.html', '.'):
    with open(match,'rb+') as thefile:
        diag = False
        fno = thefile.fileno()
        line = thefile.readline()
        while line:
            if 'oldtext' in line:
                diag = True
                thefile.seek(-len(line),1)
                thefile.write(pat.sub('newtext',line))
                thefile.flush()
                fsync(fno) 
            line = thefile.readline()
    if diag:
        cnt += 1
```

.

The instructions `thefile.flush()` and `fsync(fno)` are required after each writing in order that the file handler `thefile` points with accuracy on the exact position in the file at any moment. They allow to obtain effective writing ordered by instuction `write()`

> flush() does not necessarily write the
>   file’s data to disk. Use flush()
>   followed by os.fsync() to ensure this
>   behavior.
>   http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush

.

These programs do the minimum. So I think they are fast.

.

Nota bene **:** a file opened in mode `'rb+'` have no changing of its time of last modification if no modification has been performed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  Also, I did not know about the file mode 'rb+' so that is a good tip.  My question was actually more general: I want to replace the occurrence of a given string with a different given string.

Comment: @LandedGently If your problem is _"ACTUALLY more general"_, WHY did you write _"I'm trying to replace occurrences of 'oldtext' with 'newtext'"_ in your question ? However, it's true that in the codes in your question, there are instructions like that: ``"replace(oldtext, newtext)"`` in which ``oldtext`` and ``newtext`` are not string values but names of objects.

Comment: @LandedGently It's precisely because these instructions are contradictory with the phrasing _"occurrences of 'oldtext' with 'newtext'"_ that I asked you : _"Do you mean that you want to replace all the strings 'oldtext' present in a file with strings 'newtext' ? Or that you want to replace the occurences of the string hold by the object of name oldtext with the string hold by the object of name newtext ?"_

Comment: @LandedGently And you answered : _"I want to replace all strings 'oldtext' with 'newtext'"_ And now it's the contrary. It is disappointing. I wonder how I should have phrased my question; wasn't it enough long and trying to be understood ? You should present from the very beginning what you ACTUALLY want, not deceiving who try to help.

Comment: you're right, my original comment in response to the question in your first comment was ambiguous and not precise.  Anyhow, thanks for your help :-)