# How to insert a specific string into a specific location of a specific line in a file using a Python script?

Tags: python, string, file-io

There's this line in `'file.txt'` that says:

```
memcpy(buffer, "", 64)
```

I want to write a Python script that reads this `file.txt` and locates this line in it. Then, it proceeds to insert a specific string (stored in a variable 'data') between the two quotes ("") in that line.

For example, if the variable `data` contains the value `'foo bar'`, then the line would be modified by the Python script to:

```
memcpy(buffer, "foo bar", 64)
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
data = "foo bar"

with open('file.txt') as in_file:
    in_buffer = in_file.readlines()

with open('new.txt', "w") as out_file:
    for line in in_buffer:
        if line == 'memcpy(buffer, "", 64)':
            out_file.write("memcpy(buffer, \"data\", 64)")
        else:
            out_file.write(line)
```

It didn't work because it created the exact same replica of the file in new.txt without making any modifications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to modify lines in a file in-place?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453267/is-it-possible-to-modify-lines-in-a-file-in-place)

Comment: @PeterWood I did take a look at those questions. I did write the code after referring to these answers. However, I couldn't make it work.

Comment: The line will have a newline at the end. `line == 'memcpy(buffer, "", 64)\n'`

Comment: `$ sed 's/^wrong line$/wrong corrected line/' < file.txt > file.new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code add the condition part to the horns code. 
Use re modules sub function to replace the matching string.

```
import re

filename = "file.txt"
regex = re.compile(r'(memcpy\s*\(\s*buffer\s*,\s*")\s*("\s*,\s*64\s*)')
with open(filename) as in_file:
    in_buffer = in_file.readlines()

data = "foo bar"
with open(filename, "w") as out_file:
    for line in in_buffer:
        out_file.write(regex.sub(r'\g<1>'+data+'\g<2>', line))
```

Comment: Your code works! However, you have hard-coded the value "foo bar" in the last line. I want to be able to insert any value stored in 'data' variable. How would I do that?

Comment: @intellikid You need to go and try it, then ask another question if you're still stuck after searching.

Comment: Yep it was hardcoded. Now fixed to a variable value. it's a simple fix: just create a replace pattern by joining two strings.

Answer (score 2):

Please use

```
if line == 'memcpy(buffer, "", 64)\n':
     out_file.write('memcpy(buffer, "'+data+'", 64)\n')
```

instead of yours

```
if line == 'memcpy(buffer, "", 64)':
        out_file.write("memcpy(buffer, \"data\", 64)")
```

because the `readlines()` method DOESN'T strip newlines.

**Post Scriptum** Please note that not only the condition has to be rewritten, but also your `if` body needs a bit of reengineering, your version would write

> memcpy(buffer, "data", 64)

to the output file.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer to your question, using the suggestion in [the above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818677/how-to-insert-a-specific-string-into-a-specific-location-of-a-specific-line-in-a/28819171#comment45909133_28818677) by [Peter Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1084416/peter-wood)

Using the code shown below

```
$ cat mod_memcpy.py
from fileinput import input
data = "Papa Smurf"
for line in input(inline=1, backup=".bak"):
    if line != 'memcpy(buffer, "", 64)\n':
        print line, # << note the comma
    else:
       print 'memcpy(buffer, "'+data+'", 64)'
```

in the following way

```
$ python2 mod_memcpy.py file.txt
```

you'll get a backup file, <strike>`file.bak`</strike> `file.txt.bak` and a modified `file.txt` with the lines

```
memcpy(buffer, "", 64)
```

replaced by

```
memcpy(buffer, "Papa Smurf", 64)
```

The reference documentation for `fileinput` is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) (Python 2) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fileinput.html) (Python3).

I'd like to add that the `fileinput` module ***is the answer*** to this kind of problems, i.e., modifying a file or a sequence of files.

---

***Addendum*** the following is copied and pasted (with a slight editing to shorten the files...) from the shell

```
$ cat c.py
from __future__ import print_function
from fileinput import input
for line in input(inplace=True, backup='.bak'):
    print("00", line, end="")
$ cat dele.txt # the real file is a bit longer, hence the ellipsis
Company ABC-GH Date:31.12.2012
financial statement:4
...
$ python2 c.py dele.txt
$ cat dele.txt
00 Company ABC-GH Date:31.12.2012
00 financial statement:4
...
$ mv dele.txt.bak dele.txt
$ python3 c.py dele.txt
$ cat dele.txt
00 Company ABC-GH Date:31.12.2012
00 financial statement:4
...
$ mv dele.txt.bak dele.txt
```

It seems that the relevant part of the code, i.e.,

```
for line in input(inline=1, backup=".bak"):
```

works with Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 all the same and I have to confess that I do not understand which is the reason of the problem that the OP has experienced with my code.

Comment: Tried executing it; got this: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "replace.py", line 4, in <module>
    for line in input(inline=1, backup=".bak"):
TypeError: input() takes no keyword arguments"

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename) as in_file:
    in_buffer = in_file.readlines()

with open(filename, "w") as out_file:
    for line in in_buffer:
        if condition:
            out_file.write("something else")
        else:
            out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried your code (please see edit made to the question above). This time it created the exact replica of the file and did not make the modification. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the condition I specified. Could you please suggest how to specify the condition?

Comment: Just replace `condition` with `line == 'memcpy(buffer, "", 64)'` or whatever else you want.