# Delete specific lines in a file from Python

Tags: file, python-3.x

I have a text file with multiple lines of text.  What I would like to do is to search that file for a specific word and if that line does contain that word, how do I delete that line only.
(Python)

Comment: related: [Is it possible to modify lines in a file in-place?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5453267/4279)

Answer (score 0):

To remove lines that contain a word in the files given on the command-line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

word = 'put your word here'
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    if word not in line:
       print(line, end='') # keep the line
```