# Replace a string in file in it's original place python

Tags: python, file

I have a file where I want to replace a string, but all it's doing is appending the end of the file with the replaced string. How can I replace the original occurrences of [NAME] with a string?

Input file

```
The following are the names of company
 [NAME]
 [NAME]
 [NAME]

Incorporated
```

When I run my script with a replace I get this.

```
The following are the names of company
 [NAME]
 [NAME]
 [NAME]

Incorporated
 Julie
 Stan
 Nick
```

Desired output

```
The following are the names of company
 Julie
 Stan
 Nick

Incorporated
```

Python code

```
output=open("output.txt","r+")

output.seek(0)
name=['Julie', 'Stan', 'Nick']

i=0
for row in output:
    if name in row:
        output.write(row.replace('[NAME]',name[i]))
        i=i+1
        print(row)



for row in output:
    print(row)


output.close()
```

Comment: Don't you want to read from your input file??

Comment: Line 8: `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list` ...Do you mean `if '[NAME]' in row:`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to modify lines in a file in-place?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453267/is-it-possible-to-modify-lines-in-a-file-in-place)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the input file, and then write to the input file replacing "[NAME]":

```
input = open("input.txt")
output = open("output.txt","w")
name=['Julie', 'Stan', 'Nick']

i = 0

for row in input:
   if "[NAME]" in row:
      row=row.replace("[NAME]",name[i])
      i+=1
   output.write(row)

input.close()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one-liner:

```
output.replace("[NAME]", "%s") % tuple(name)
```

But, amount of names must always be the same as in file.

Comment: What version of Python? I'm getting an `AttributeError`, no attribute called "replace".

Comment: 2.6 and 2.7 works the same. output must be string, not just opened file:
output=open("output.txt","r+").read()

Comment: Ok, thanks for that clarification. So that the asker knows, this just converts the file to a string and performs replacement on the string. He still needs to write the contents of the string back to the file.