# How to delete a specific line and the following n lines from a txt file?

Tags: python, sed, text-files, edit

I'm creating a program to update a text file, that has a list of cities:

```
New York City
New York
USA

Newark
New Jersey
USA

Toronto
Ontario
Canada
```

If I wanted to delete the details for Newark using a bash script, I can do this:

```
sed -i "/Newark/,+3d" test.txt
```

And that would leave me with the following:

```
New York City
New York
USA

Toronto
Ontario
Canada
```

However, I would like to do this in Python, and I'm having issues figuring out how to delete the following lines, after the line with Newark.  I can delete Newark:

```
with open('test.txt') as oldfile, open('test2.txt', 'w') as newfile:
        for line in oldfile:
            if not "Newark" in line:
                newfile.write(line)

os.remove('test.txt')
os.rename('test2.txt', 'test.txt')
```

But this does nothing for the remaining two lines, and creates a new file I then have to use to replace the original file.

1. How can I go about mimicing the sed command's functionality with Python?
2. Is there any way to do an in file edit, so I do not have to create and replace the file everytime I need to delete from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a counter ? Here it is:

```py
with open('test.txt') as oldfile, open('test2.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    skip = 0
    for line in oldfile:
        if "Newark" in line:
            skip = 3
        elif skip > 0:
            skip = skip - 1
        else:
            newfile.write(line)
```

Edit:

I only answered the first question. [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) support file editing, please have a look here: [How to search and replace text in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17140886/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-file)
Btw, I would recommend also [in-place](https://pypi.org/project/in-place) because [it doesn't hijack stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49873196/2437450)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fileinput` module to edit files in place:

```
import fileinput
import itertools

skip = 3
with fileinput.input("test.txt", inplace=True) as f:
     for line in f:
         if "Newark" not in line:
             # stdout is redirected to the file
             sys.stdout.write(line)
         else:
             # Skip lines
             next(itertools.islice(f, skip, skip), None)
```