# replace sub-string in a file using regex with python

Tags: python

suppose I have a file.txt with line
aaaa = /bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff

I would like replace ccc with xxx

I have tried next without success

```
import re
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(file.txt, inplace=True):
    re.sub(r'(ccc)', 'xxx', line)
```

Comment: re.sub('ccc','xxx',aaaa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost the same question has been asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453267/is-it-possible-to-modify-lines-in-a-file-in-place).
In your case the answer would look like this:

```
for line in fileinput.input('file.txt', inplace=True):
    print(re.sub(r'(ccc)', 'xxx', line), end='')
```

See above link to learn about alternatives and efficiency. (Also note the quotes around file.txt)

Short explanation:

- `print()`in Python prints lines with a newline character by default. To prevent this, `end=''` needs to be specified as keyword argument.
- `r'(ccc)'` contains a pair of group parentheses which is not necessary in your case, so you can simply write `r'ccc'` as already pointed out by the two previous posts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m = re.sub(r'ccc', r'xxx', "/bbb/ccc/ddd/eee/fff")
#OUTPUT: /bbb/xxx/ddd/eee/fff
```