# Remove string from text file after print (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I have the following code that pulls a list from a txt file and then prints one line at a time. The problem I am having is that I want the code to remove that line from the txt file after it has printed it.

I have tried using a few different methods I found online but had no success on maiking it work.

Would any have any idea's on how to achive this?

```
import time
from time import sleep
import random

my_file=open('testlist.txt','r')
file_lines=my_file.readlines()
my_file.close()

for line in file_lines:

try:
    sep = line.split(":")
    select_list = ["test " + sep[0] +  "? " + sep[1], "test " + sep[0] + "! " + sep[1], "test " + sep[0] + "? " + sep[1]]

    print(random.choice(select_list))


    sleep(1) 

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Basically after the "print(random.choice(select_list))", we would want to delete "line" from "testlist.txt".

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I hope my answer below isn't too daunting but help you in understanding some quirky python logic better.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through some logic and see how to achieve the results you are expecting.

## Humanly / Intuitively, the actions are

**1. Read files line-by-line to memory**

```
my_file=open('testlist.txt','r')
file_lines=my_file.readlines()
my_file.close()
```

It would be a better practice to consider using `with` context managers (it will automatically help you close the file one you are out of the indentation from the `with` scope, i.e.

```
with open('testlist.txt','r') as my_file:
    file_lines = my_file.readlines()
```

**2. For each line that is read, (a) split it by `:` character, (b) perform a few string operations and (c) randomly select one of the output from (2b), i.e**

```
for line in file_lines:
    sep = line.split(":")
    select_list = ["test " + sep[0] +  "? " + sep[1], "test " + sep[0] + "! " + sep[1], "test " + sep[0] + "? " + sep[1]]
    print(random.choice(select_list))
```

**2b. Now, lets take a look at (2b) and see what we are trying to achieve**, i.e.

```
select_list = ["test " + sep[0] +  "? " + sep[1], "test " + sep[0] + "! " + sep[1], "test " + sep[0] + "? " + sep[1]]
```

We produce 3 items in the `select_list`, where it seems the `"test " + sep[0] + "? " + sep[1]` has 2 occurence and the `"test " + sep[0] + "! " + sep[1]` is included once.

- `"test " + sep[0] + "? " + sep[1]`
- `"test " + sep[0] + "! " + sep[1]`
- `"test " + sep[0] + "? " + sep[1]`

in any case, the `select_list = [ ... ]` is a valid line of code.

**2c. Regarding the `print(random.choice(select_list))` line, it doesn't affect any variables and it's just randomly choosing an item from the `select_list`**

## Going back to original question,

> I want the code to remove that line from the txt file after it has printed it.

Q: Would this mean removing the line from the original `file_lines` in `open('testlist.txt','r')`?

A: If so, then it would be **removing all lines** from the original `testlist.txt`, because if everything would checks out for step 2b and 2c (in the `try` part of the code).

But if step 2b or 2c throws an error and get caught in the `except`, then it would be a line that you won't want to throw out (as per your original question).

In that case, it looks like what you want to get eventually is a list of lines that falls into the `except` scope of the code.

If so, then you would be looking at something like this:

```
# Reading the original file.
with open('testlist.txt','r') as my_file:
    # Opening a file to write the lines that falls into the exception
    with open('testlist-exceptions.txt', 'w') as fout:
        # Iterate through the original file line by line.
        for line in my_file:
            # Step 2a.
            sep = line.split(":")

            # Supposedly step 2b, but since this is the only 
            # point of the code that can throw an exception
            # most probably because there's no sep[1], 
            # you should instead check the length of the sep variable.

            if len(sep) < 2:  # i.e. does not have sep[1].
                # Write to file.
                fout.write(line)
            else:  # Otherwise, perform the step 2b.
                select_list = ["test " + sep[0] +  "? " + sep[1], "test " + sep[0] + "! " + sep[1], "test " + sep[0] + "? " + sep[1]]
                print(random.choice(select_list))
```

## Now the new logic is a lot simpler than the intuition based logic you have in the original code but achieves the same output that you are expecting.

The new logic is as such:

1. Open the original file for reading, open another file to write the file that I expect
2. Read the file line by line

- Split the file by `:`
- Check if it allows the string operation to join the `sep[0]` and `sep[1]`

  - if yes, perform the string operation to create `select_list` and choose one of the item in `select_list` to print to console
  - if no, print out that line to the output file.

---

If for some reason, you really want to work with the file in place with Python, then take a look at [Is it possible to modify lines in a file in-place?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5453267/610569)

And if you really need to reduce memory footprint and want something that can edit lines of the file in-place, then you would have to dig a little into file `seek` function https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

---

Some unsolicited Python suggestions (hope this helps)

- When you need to delete something from file, if disk space allows, don't delete it, create another file with the expected output without the deleted lines.
- Whenever possible, try to treat files that you want to read as immutable, and less like Perl-style in-place files that allows edits
- It's tempting to do try-excepts when you just want something to work, but catch-all excepts are hard to debug and normally shows that the logic of the steps can be better. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I would give you example but better try to follow this guide there is various ways , first issue is opening the file with 'r' mode

[Deleting lines](https://pynative.com/python-delete-lines-from-file/)