# Write on a txt file a sequence nuber for the last row

Tags: python, append, row

I have a python script with inputs that I used to modify a txt file.

```
from datetime import date
import datetime

#oggi = date.today()
oggi = datetime.datetime.now()
oggi1 = oggi.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

f = open("/storage/emulated/0/Python/stadio_2023_2024.txt", "a")

avversaria = input("Avversaria: ")
competizione = input("SA, CI, CU o Am: ")
dove = input("C, T o N: ")

f.write("\n" + oggi1 + " " + avversaria + " " + competizione + " " + dove)

f = open("/storage/emulated/0/Python/stadio_2023_2024.txt", "r")

testo = f.read()

print(testo)

f.close()
```

What I am trying to do, is to also append at the beginning of each new row a sequence number with the format 001.

I would like the output to be:

```
001 30/12/2023 Juventus SA T
002 03/01/2024 Cremonese CI C
...
132 04/03/2031 Liverpool CU T
```

Any hints?

Comment: you should use a loop.

Comment: You will need to read the entire file and count the number of lines. Then you can add a new line with an appropriate sequence number

Comment: @Nesi What would be the functionality of the loop that you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by opening the file in a+ mode. This ensures that the file will be created if it doesn't already exist. However, if it does exist then the file offset will be at EOF. So you need to seek to BOF. Then consume the file's entire contents to determine how many lines are already in it. Then acquire user input and format the date appropriately.

```
from datetime import datetime

FILENAME = "/storage/emulated/0/Python/stadio_2023_2024.txt"

with open(FILENAME, "a+") as data:
    data.seek(0)
    seqno = len(data.readlines()) + 1
    date = datetime.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    avversaria = input("Avversaria: ")
    competizione = input("SA, CI, CU o Am: ")
    dove = input("C, T o N: ")
    output = f"{seqno:03d} {date} {avversaria} {competizione} {dove}"
    print(output, file=data)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```py
rfile = open("file/to/read", "r")
wfile = open("new/file", "w")
num = 0
while True:
    line = rfile.readline() # read one line at a time
    if line == "": # if line is empty you reached the EOF
        break
    num += 1
    wfile.write(f"{num :03d} " + line)
rfile.close()
wfile.close()
```

I don't really like this solution and probably there are better ways than this, but it's simple and easy to understand.

With this `f"{num :03d}"` you get the number in *num* with 3 leading zeros.

---

If you want to edit the file *in place* (I'm not really fond of it) read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5453267/23167491), it can be helpful.

Comment: OP clearly wants to modify an existing file - not create a new one

Comment: yes, but generally it is better to avoid modifying the file you are reading

Comment: You're right, I thought that OP wanted to read the file and modify the already existing lines, but as you pointed out and I thank you for that, I misunderstood the OP's request. However, even if a method, function or whatever exists that doesn't mean that it's safe to use (e.g. gets() in C).